# Possible to calculate the $n$ in $0.42 = P^n$ where $P$ is a matrix?

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm not sure if this is possible at all - sorry if it isn't and I would delete my question if you told me so. But let's say there is a transition matrix of a Markov chain
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4\\ 
0.2 & 0.7 & 0.1\\ 
0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix}$$

And the question is something like this: "How many steps do you need to reach state $2$ from state $1$ with a probability of $0.42$?"

I know the solution is $n=2$ (because if you take $P^2$ then row $1$ , column $2$ of this matrix, the element is element $0.42$).

But is it possible to find this solution like that? I couldn't think of another formula than this one, but I don't know how to solve it for $n$ ? :c

$$0.42 = P^n$$

Comment: Hint: If you have enough time, you can diagonalise, that is $P=UDU^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal. Then $P^n = UD^nU^{-1}$., Then having all components of $P^n$, call them $a_{i,j}(n)$, you want to find for which $n$ you have $a_{1,2}(n) = 0.42$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of an $n \times n$ matrix gives you an $n$-step recurrence for the powers of the matrix.  In this case the characteristic polynomial
is $\lambda^3 - 1.5\; \lambda^2 + 0.54 \; \lambda - 0.04 $
so $$P^k - 1.5\; P^{k-1} + 0.54\; P^{k-2} - 0.04 \; P^{k-3} = 0$$
Solving the recurrence $a(k) - 1.5\; a(k-1) + 0.54 \; a(k-2) - 0.04\; a(k-3) = 0$
with initial condition $a(0) = 0$, $a(1) = P_{12} = 0.3$, $a(2) = P^2_{12} = 0.42$
gives you $$ a(k) = \frac{1 - (2/5)^k}{2}$$
and you can solve $a(k) = t$ for $k$ to find what power of $P$ has $P^k_{12}=t$.

However, in most cases there will be several terms with different constants to the power $k$, and also possibly powers of $k$, so in general it may not be possible to solve the equation for $a(k)$ in closed form.